# Sorting an array to even and odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, static

I wrote a program to sort an array to odd and even numbers using **ArrayList** class, but when I tried to display the two **ArrayLists** via **display** method there is no output.
**note:-** when I try to display them in the classify method everything go well.
here my class ..

```
import java.util.*;
public class SortNumbers{
    private static int[] array = {8,78,20,3,27,30,45,25,14};
    private static List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void classify(int[] arr, List even , List odd){
        even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
            if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
                even.add(arr[i]);

            else
                odd.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void display(List<Integer> list){
        for(Integer i : list)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        classify(array,even,odd);
        display(even);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out the reason ??

Comment: @Mike If you code in assembly it may be the case - in Java you can count on the JVM to perform that kind of optimisation...

Comment: Just realized this is for Java. Sorry, Optimization is indeed handled by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `even` list is empty: you create a local variable in `classify` which hides the static field.

Just remove:

```
even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

from your classify method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the arrays around or reinitialize them:

```
import java.util.*;
public class SortNumbers{
    private static int[] array = {8,78,20,3,27,30,45,25,14};
    private static List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void classify(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
            if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
                even.add(array[i]);

            else
                odd.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void display(List<Integer> list){
        for(Integer i : list)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        classify();
        display(even);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the local objects with local reference  u created that become destroyed when function ends in your classify method with same name as instance members

even = new ArrayList();

odd = new ArrayList();

```
public static void classify(int[] arr, List even , List odd){
                // even = new ArrayList<Integer>();  local reference created with same name as instance member
                // odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();  local reference created with same name as instance member
                 for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
                     if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
                         even.add(arr[i]);

                     else
                         odd.add(arr[i]);
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove:

```
even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**and**

Also remove all the parameters from classify.  So it should now look like:

```
public static void classify(){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            even.add(arr[i]);

        else
            odd.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

The static parameters do not need to be passed into the method as you are creating local copies by attempting to do that.